# Google Sheet Script - add date in colum before the copied

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the following cope in google sheets to copy a range of values from a row on a source sheet.
It appends it to the destination sheet as values starting in the 2nd column.
This works fine, but i now want to add on column 1 the date/time "localDateTime" that the script runs, but i just don't know how to get this done.

Can somebody help please

```
function copyInfo() {
  // get date & time
  var localDateTime = new Date()
  // other variables
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Performance");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PortfolioTrend");

  // get source range
  // getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
  var source = copySheet.getRange(103,5,1,7);

  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,+2,1,7);


  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination, {contentsOnly:true});

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the value of `localDateTime` to a left side of the 1st column of `destination`.

For this, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
source.copyTo(destination, {contentsOnly:true});
```

#### To:

```
source.copyTo(destination, {contentsOnly:true});
destination.offset(0, -1, 1, 1).setValue(localDateTime);  // Added
```

#### Reference:

- [offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Thaks for educating me on the accept function. I found it and used it. Many thanks.

Comment: @Marco Thank you for your response.